# Problem with accented characters in ClassicThesis template

Tags: input-encodings, classicthesis, spanish

I've just downloaded the [template for ClassicThesis in CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) and I was trying to use it writing some spanish text. I've only changed the title and name of the document (in the `classicthesis-config.tex` file). The document compiles, but the accented characters (like in 'Teoría') are wrong.

Now, I tell you what changes I made that are supposed to prepare the template to recieve accented characters:

- In the `classicthesis-config.tex` file I have the following lines:

  ```
  \PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}   % latin9 (ISO-8859-9) = latin1+"Euro sign"
  \usepackage{inputenc}
  ```

  (as you see, the author recommends using latin9 encoding, but i'm using TeXworks, which works in utf8. Anyway, neither latin9 nor latin1 work.)

  ```
  \PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
  \usepackage{fontenc}     
  \usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
  ```
- I have the following ones, too, but I think this has nothing to do with the encoding problem:

  ```
  % Spanish languages need extra options in order to work with this template
  \PassOptionsToPackage{spanish,es-lcroman}{babel}
  \usepackage{babel}
  ```
- And in the `ClassicThesis.tex` file I've put `spanish` option in the `\documentclass`and selected the spanish language via `\selectlanguage{spanish}`, but, as I said, I think this has nothing to do with the encoding, it must be related with the 'Figure', 'Table', etc. stuff.

My distribution is MiKTeX 2.9 in Windows 7.

PS: I'm compiling with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: `wrong` doesn't give much of a clue, do you get an error, or the wrong letter, or nothing. Are you sure your source is encoded in utf8?

Comment: As I said, I get wrong letters, the ones with accents. Instead of them, strange characters appear (something like Ã and a square, where there has to be an 'í').

If I write `\'i` I get the right character, but I want to write 'í' and get my character.

in the preferences of the editor it's set utf8 as the enconding, so I think it is. If I compile a simple document with this encoding, the accented characters work fine.

And I don't get any error.

Comment: They are not "strange letters" the accented capital A is a classic sign that you have encoded the file in utf8 but have processed it as latin1.

Comment: ... so I would guess that your editor is making new files in utf8 but that file is copied from some original template and it is keeping its encoding. I don't know the editor but you should be able to force save to utf-8 (or just start a new file in utf8 and then cut and paste the old text in.

Comment: I use spanish language a lot too, and I'm behind @DavidCarlisle on this one.  You should be able to get rid of whatever is messing with your encoding

Comment: Finally got it! But still I don't understand how... I tell you. I've  saved the file as latin encoding and it worked, even with the `utf8` option for `inputenc`! So I really don't know what's happening here.

Answer (score 2):

I can guarantee you that using a code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
    Sólo una pequeña demostración.

    S\'{o}lo una peque\~{n}a demostraci\'{o}n
\end{document}
```

Will produce a correct output like this:

[image]

Please make sure non of your packages required by your template or any other setting in your editor conflicts with the specifications mentioned above.

As David Carlisle said in the comments:

> ... so I would guess that your editor is making new files in utf8 but
>   that file is copied from some original template and it is keeping its
>   encoding. I don't know the editor but you should be able to force save
>   to utf-8 (or just start a new file in utf8 and then cut and paste the
>   old text in.

Comment: @David Pravos Use a cross-platform unicode LaTeX editor from [big list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) with **Platforms: all, Unicode:Yes** and Be careful while opening/saving `unknown-files-with-unknown-encoding` normally editors would detect automatically file encoding, otherwise mention explicitly input encoding via `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Editor encoding,File encoding, and `utf8` option inside inputenc must be same to avoid any encoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [error for special characters in \section in a classicthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166000/error-for-special-characters-in-section-in-a-classicthesis)
worked for me, I used:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

Comment: Would you consider this a duplicate then?