# error for special characters in \section in a classicthesis

Tags: sectioning, input-encodings, classicthesis

Provided the following tex document using classicthesis, produces an error. How can I use direct input of special characters in `\section` in classicthesis?

I do not want to write e.g. `\~{n}` in the text, as it is not readable as easily as writing `ñ`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
    \section{umlauts å à É Ü }
    text
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
! Argument of \@firstofone has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9     \section{umlauts å à É Ü }

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: \usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard setup of `classicthesis` uses `soul` for spacing small caps; add the `pdfspacing` options that uses `microtype` features:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nochapters,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\section{umlauts å à É Ü}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]